# Why should I use the form helper and not write my own html forms

Tags: java, playframework, formhelper

I am learning about play 2.0 and I have got a question on the form helpers.

For me it all comes down to what benefit is it actually giving by using it  in the templates?  Am I using it correctly?

First: using the form helper:

```
@form(action = routes.Application.addAccount("blank")) {
  @inputText(accountForm("id"))
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="submit ID"/><br />
}
```

Why is that better then just defining

```
Enter your id "<input type="text" name="id"/>"
```

I know I can use the form model to help with validation on the server side.   - that's where I see the great benefits of form helper.  But where does it help to actually include the form in the Scala template?  Can i use the form helper to automatically generate useful things in the html like client side validation, etc?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it helps you generate a lot more than just  tags. From the documentation:

> You feed them with a form field, and they display the corresponding HTML form control, with a populated value, constraints and errors

and

> A rendered field does not only consist of an  tag, but may also need a  and a bunch of other tags used by your CSS framework to decorate the field.

(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaFormHelpers)

So instead of

```
<label for=...>
... error mesages
<input ... 
</label>
```

you have just one readable line

```
@inputText(accountForm("id"))
```

**EDIT:**
It will also read constraints on your java beans, e.g

```
@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.MinLength(5)
public String firstName;
```

and use html5 browser validations and display the coinstraints to the user.
(http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms)

Comment: aaah thanks - really helpful - just to clarify, when you say constraints and errors, do you mean some client code to prevent certain values being entered? - disclaimer really new to web programming but am very keen.

Comment: @SaadAttieh : if frant's answer was helpful for you (and it was as we can see) please mark it as correct answer and/or upvote.